# Creating a random number of objects

Tags: c++, class, object

I've created a class, let's call it `classA`. I want to create in function `main()` a random number of objects. How can I do this whilst naming them differently? I've tried out of desperation:

```
int a[100],i ,rnd;

srand ( time(NULL) ); 

rnd=(rand() %100);      
for(i=0;i<=rnd;i++){
    classa a[i];
}
```

but I knew it would not work.

Comment: use std::vector. Vectors can be dynamically resized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
std::vector<a> v(rand() % 10000);  // creates [0, 10000) objects
```

Comment: Except use `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `std::mt19937` to avoid modulo bias.

Comment: @rightfold One talk and suddenly rand() is evil :). Is it uniform after modulo ? - no (usually not, that is). Do you actually care? I'd dare to claim you usually don't.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth No, it was problematic before then, but I guess the problems are getting wider coverage now. I [was](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8157725/365496) [recommending](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8317726/365496) [against](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9485149/365496) usage of `rand()` and in favor of `<random>` pretty much since C++11 was finished, citing the many of the same issues as STL pointed out in his presentation.

Comment: `rand()` was and still is fine. You just have to know its weaknesses. Sure you can use stuff from `<random>` for more accurate random numbers (is that an oxymoron?) but it comes with a price. For simple stupid things like this rand() (and modulo) are still fine.

Comment: @bames53 ofcourse it existed before, shees, this was supposed to point out the recent wider coverage actually... just nevermind :).

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth What I mean is that even before that presentation these problems were brought up in pretty much every question that mentioned `rand()`. Now it's still brought up in every thread, just maybe by more users.

Comment: @rightfold: There was no requirement for uniformity. The OP already seems to have decided a mechanism for getting randomness...

Comment: @KerrekSB and how will I be able to refer to those objects?
I was hoping for something like "obj[i]" or so, so I can use every object separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

std::map<std::string, a> objects;

for (int i=0; i < dis(gen); ++i)
      objects.insert(std::make_pair("obj_"+std::to_string(i), a()));
```