# rand() only sets variable to 0

Tags: c++, random, ctime

I am working on a rock, paper, scissors game and one of the ways I am setting the computer's choice is through rand(). I `#include <ctime>`, seed rand at the start of main with `srand(time(0));` and I call it in a function definition with `computerWeaponChoiceV = (rand() % 3) + 1;`.  However, when I test my program it always prints `computerWeaponChoiceV` to be 0.

Am I doing something wrong with `rand()`?  If you need more of my code please let me know.

Comment: Some more code would help

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] example.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129705/why-is-rand-anything-always-0-in-c?rq=1

Comment: The code you've shown is correct. The problem must be in the code you didn't show.

Comment: `rand()` is never negative, and the modulus will not change this. How can the value then be zero after adding `1`? Have you really run the code snippets you show?

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Answer (score -4):

i'm not used with c++ (only programmed with c++ a pair of times) but I think the issue is on rand declaration.

```
Try using rand() % 3 + 1;
```

If this don't work regard to time(0), it may take a "NOW" value to properly randomize (usually programming languages take miliseconds to randomize).
PD: I may be wrong on what i said of time, comment on there if those two solutions doens't serve you.

There is an example of rand from 1 to 10 working:

```
/* rand example: guess the number */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  int iSecret, iGuess;

  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  /* generate secret number between 1 and 10: */
  iSecret = rand() % 10 + 1;

  do {
    printf ("Guess the number (1 to 10): ");
    scanf ("%d",&iGuess);
    if (iSecret<iGuess) puts ("The secret number is lower");
    else if (iSecret>iGuess) puts ("The secret number is higher");
  } while (iSecret!=iGuess);

  puts ("Congratulations!");
  return 0;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Changing rand to how you suggested still does nothing, it only prints a 0

Comment: and setting srand (time(NULL)); instead srand (time(0));?

Comment: srand (time(NULL));
and 
computerWeaponChoiceV = rand() % 3 + 1; and, oviously check that you've the proper libraries charged (as i put on the example)