# C++11 custom uniform integer distribution implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, random, distribution

I write code in C++ that need to be cross-platform. I need a uniform integer pseudo-random number generator to give the same results on different platforms (not cryptographic strength). As I understand from posts the existing `std::uniform_int_distribution` is implementation dependent. I was not able to find an existing integral numbers implementation, the closest I found was real numbers implementation: [C++11 random number distributions are not consistent across platforms -- what alternatives are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al). So I wrote my own simple implementation:

```
template <typename T = int>
class SimpleIntDistribution
{
public:
    typedef T result_type;

public:
    SimpleIntDistribution(T a = {}, T b = {}) :
        _a{ a }, _b{ b } {}

    void reset() {}

    template <class Gen>
    T operator()(Gen& g)
    {
        using gen_res_type = typename Gen::result_type;
        // number of elements in distribution range
        gen_res_type distRange = static_cast<gen_res_type>(
            _b - _a + static_cast<T>(1));
        // normalized generator value
        gen_res_type normGenValue = g() - g.min();
        return _a + normGenValue % distRange;
    }

    T a() const { return _a; }
    T b() const { return _b; }

protected:
    T _a;
    T _b;
};

class Rand_int
{
public:
    Rand_int(int low, int high) : dist{ low, high } {}
    int operator()() { return dist(re); }
    void seed(int s) { re.seed(s); }

private:
    // std::default_random_engine re;
    std::mt19937 re;
    // std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
    SimpleIntDistribution<> dist;
};

int main()
{
    Rand_int r{ -10, 10 };
    r.seed(100);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int val = r();
        std::cout << val << ", ";
    }
}
```

I would be happy to receive comments on this code to understand potential pitfalls. Another option, if anybody could point to a better simple implementation code (not existing heavy libraries like boost, etc.)

Comment: Have you looked at boost? That's what the standard library is based on and has a cross platform implementation

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, it's an option, but I have a constraint not to use boost for some platforms.

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: Boost is very open source.  You could familiarize yourself with their implementation. At least for inspiration.

Comment: Reducing to a range by (just) taking the remainder causes bias in the output. You just about need to add a loop to reject the numbers that would lead to bias, as discussed in one of my older answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129979/179910

Comment: You could also take a look at some standard library implementations.

Comment: Seed for `std::mt19937` should by type `std::uint32_t`, i.e., it should be unsigned. [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/seed) uses a typedef: `std::mt19937::result_type`, which is an alias for `std::uint_fast32_t`.

Comment: Take a look at [xoshiro256++/xoshiro256**](https://prng.di.unimi.it). The implementations at the link are C rather than C++, but that shouldn't be a show-stopper. The amount of state in Mersenne Twister is overkill, which actually leads to issues if it's poorly initialized. These Xoshiro generators have plenty of state to allow for parallel applications, are blazingly fast, and pass all the statistical tests in standardized test suites for PRNGs. As indicated on the linked page, this is one of the default generators for Rust and is used in the JavaScript engines of several web browsers.

Comment: @JerryCoffin There's been some interesting work on avoiding modulo bias since you posted your answer to SO in 2010. Check out [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3230636) relatively recent (2019) paper for an extremely efficient nearly divisionless algorithm to maintain uniformity over arbitrary ranges. I used a port of the implementation you'll find in the paper's appendix, along with Xoshiro256**, to create a Ruby random number generator gem which significantly outperforms the built-in MT19937 implementation of `rand`.

Comment: @pjs: That's an excellent paper. Thanks for the link.

Comment: If you're trying to create a test engine, then generate a test dataset on a single machine and port it as a small database on any targets that run the test. Use `<random>` only when the results are supposed to be actually random or just to generate the test dataset.